# How to bind columns definition dynamically on KendoUI

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to make a dynamic binding to the columns fields of a grid on kendoui.

```
<table    id="checkout-grid"
                class="k-grid"
                data-role="grid"
                data-bind="source: items"
                data-row-template="checkout-form-item-template"
                data-scrollable="false"
                data-columns="[
                        { title: 'Name', width: '300px'},
                        'Description',
                        { title: 'Price', width: '50px' },
                        { title: 'Quantity', width: '50px' },
                        { title: 'Total', width: '100px' }
                    ]">
        </table>
```

The problem is that I need to set the headers of the columns on different languages.

How i can make a binding of that definition without using the javascript kendoGrid method over the object.

I try to bind the data-colums value from the viewmodel but it throw a not support binding exception, even using the attr value.

How can I perform a dynamic binding of that field?.

Comment: Maybe you could use Kendo Grid columns method to set new set of column when you need columns in different language?

    var grid = $("#checkout-grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.columns = // set of new columns

Answer (score 0):

First, I see a problem with your `Grid` definition where you say the `title` but not the `field`.

Answering your question and knowing that you don't want to dynamically generate the `columns.definition`, I would propose you defining it as:

```
<table id="checkout-grid"
    class="k-grid"
    data-role="grid"
    data-bind="source: items"
    data-scrollable="false"
    data-columns="[
        { field: 'Name', width: '300px'},
        'Description',
        { field: 'Price', width: '50px' },
        { field: 'Quantity', width: '50px' },
        { field: 'Total', width: '100px' }
        ]">
    <thead>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Descripción</td>
        <td>Precio</td>
        <td>Cantidad</td>
        <td>Total</td>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I.e., Add a `thead` definition with the localization. But obviously if your server can do this, can also generate something like:

```
<table id="checkout-grid"
    class="k-grid"
    data-role="grid"
    data-bind="source: items"
    data-scrollable="false"
    data-columns="[
        { field: 'Name', title: 'Nombre', width: '300px'},
        { field: 'Description', title: 'Descripción' },
        { field: 'Price', width: '50px', title: 'Precio' },
        { field: 'Quantity', width: '50px', title: 'Cantidad' },
        { field: 'Total', width: '100px', title: 'Total' }
    ]"
>
```

Comment: Sorry, That is not working. I am working with spa. I try to bind the html of the rewrited thead fields but not work. I will try to make a custom binding property for assign that property for now.